# Vb.net listview check event

Tags: vb.net

I'm currently using vs 2013 and coding in vb.
I have my application almost complete, but i'm trying to change a checked listbox to a checked listview.
My problem is that when i try to load the checkboxes on the application start, the listview event for the checkboxes fires up, this didn't happen on the c_listbox, I could load the checkboxes in the code without firing up the event, any solution for this problem?
Ty in advance.

Comment: Not sure what might be the problem. Please, can you post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When items are added to a ListView, whether the LV is Check style or not, the CheckChanged event fires.  This would include the InitializeComponents when the form is created.  Just add an ignore flag until the form is loaded:

```
private FormLoaded As Boolean = False

Sub Form_Load(.... 
    '...
    ' set any checks from program/bus logic here 
    ' so the checks dont respond to your own toggling
    FormLoaded = True           ' the only place it is set
End Sub

Private Sub LV_ItemChecked.....
    If FormLoaded = False Then Exit Sub

     '...Normal code to execute when loaded
End Sub
```

A more complex way is to strip the Handles clauses from the ItemChecked event and add them at the end of the form load event:

```
 Private Sub LV_ItemChecked(ByVal sender As Object, _
            ...) 
    ' remove the 'Handles LV.ItemChecked'
    ' so your form is not 'listening' at form load
   ... Normal code
 End Sub

Sub Form_Load(.... 
    '...
    ' set any checks from program/bus logic here 
    ' so the checks dont respond to your own toggling
    AddHandler LV.ItemChecked, AddressOf LV_ItemChecked
    ...etc
End Sub
```

Comment: Tyvm, its not a perfect solution but it worked fine. Dunno why the lv check event differs from the listbox one tough :S ty for your fast response :)

Comment: sry, 1st time using this, i tried to upvote it but it dind't let me, hadn't notice the check sign ;p

Comment: @user3036777: You need to have more reputation to upvote. A minimum of 15, IIRC.